# How to launch a host app using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minikube, podman

When running a Docker Compose project, it would be nice to be able to open an app with certain parameters on the host operating system (on which `docker-compose up` is being invoked). This would be legitimately useful when running web apps. For example, I would love to have Docker Compose automatically open a browser on the host with location of http://localhost:8080, when I run `docker-compose run`, rather than manually opening a browser and entering the http://localhost:8080. Just the way we see in Minikube (e.g when running `minikube service web-deployment`).
I am aware there are parameters to use in docker-compose.yml to pass commands to run in containers, like `command` and `entrypoint`, but I don't know if that is possible for applications on the host OS.

Comment: what is a host app?

Comment: @TheFool OP gave an example in the question: `I would love to open a browser on host with location of http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes, I was able to read that. It's still not clear to me, what is the question here. I am asking for the definition of a *host app*. I am also not sure what the specific problem is, given the fact that docker / compose resolves a lot around serving stuff over some protocol, i.e. http. Minikube is also using container images the same way, as OP mentioned themselves.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to run a command on the host when executing `docker-compose run...` or are you asking if you can run a command on the host from a container?

Comment: @Johnny I meant the former.

Answer (score 6):

Compose can do a pretty limited set of things.  It can build Docker images, without any ordering constraints, and it can start (presumably long-running) Docker containers, with very limited ordering constraints.  It can create a couple of associated Docker objects like networks and named volumes.  That's literally all it can do, though; it cannot do larger-scale orchestration task ("run this migration container to completion, then run this application") or launch non-Docker tasks.

You might use some host-based tool to manage this instead.  Even a shell script would be enough; possibly something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# start the container stack
# (assumes the caller has permission to do this)
docker-compose up -d

# wait for the service to be ready
while ! curl --fail --silent --head http://localhost:8080; do
  sleep 1
done

# open the browser window
open http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Yep. This is what I was going to suggest also. Just write a script that runs your `docker-compose` and any other command on the host. It IS actually elegant, don't be fooled by thinking this is an old school approach.